# When i click the url its redirecting to the same page, i want its to redirect to the link

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

[image]I am using get method to fetch the data from third-party API and I am appending to list its working well but when I click the link it's reloading and it's not redirecting the URL link

Comment: Is it appending data properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to replace the `href='#'` attribute with url.

Replace the line before the comment with this line

```
$("#news").append("<a href='" + url +"' id = 'url'>" + url + "</a>");
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

Please put the URL in your a tag when you append it in I'd news. Seems that you put a # only instead of a exact url. That's why it keeps refreshing the page every time you clicked it. See code below

```
$("#news").append("<a href='" + url +"' id = 'url'>" + url +</a>");
```